# CookieDomain is not being set in CookieAuthenticationOptions ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net Core Identity in my ASP.Net application to manage login sessions. 
To achieve this I am using the *app.UseCookieAuthentication* function to create and store an **.AspNet.CookieAuthentication** cookie so that the browser remembers the login session for the user.

This is to prevent the user having to reenter their credentials everytime they open the website. The login session runs for 8 hours.

The domain of my web application which handles this login request and creates the cookie is located at:

**app1.domain1.co.uk**

However I wish the domain of the cookie to be just set to:

**domain1.co.uk**

This is because I plan to have another application running on a seperate sub-domain at the location:

**app2.domain1.co.uk**

This application is also using Asp.Net Core Identity and accesses the exact same Identity database as 'app1'. When the user logins on the *app1.domain1.co.uk* sucessfully and then opens *app2.domain1.co.uk* I want the application to pick up the login session stored from app1 and use it to automatically login to app2 to prevent the user having to reenter their login details again.

The code I have for the app.UseCookieAuthentication function is as follows:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            CookieDomain = ".domain1.co.uk"
        });
```

As you can see I specify that the domain of the cookie should be at '.domain1.co.uk'. However when I test my application and view the cookie within any browser, the domain is still set to **app1.domain1.co.uk**.

Any help or indications as to why the cookie is refusing to set the domain to what I specified is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: getting same issue, any success on solving this?